# Joomla: restart list item numbering

Tags: css, list, joomla, html-lists

I'm Trying to create a 3 column ordered list in Joomla. I've tried these methods for continuing the numbering:

`<ol style="counter-reset: item 11;">`

to start the numbering from 11 for column two. And also this:

`<ol start="11">`

But neither of these work. Are there any restrictions on this in Joomla?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably split a single list into columns by styling the list with a fixed height, then styling your list items so that they're positioned where you want.  You could assign each list item in a given column a class, then give the columns a margin-left.

Alternatively you could absolutely position your list items.

Both solutions are pretty dirty, but I think they would work.

Is this something you'll need other users to be able to do for themselves in Joomla?

Comment: Easy said than done :) do you have an example that works with Joomla? Even the basic styling I showed in the question doesn't seem to work. And I'm talking Joomla 1.6. My method SHOULD work but doesn't that's the problem. IF you think yours works please show me an example.

Comment: actually, if you could send me a link to your site, I'd like to play around with it in Firebug and see if I can get that to happen.